# How do I overload LINQ string.Contains()?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

For a generic filter I am implementing, I need to modify the following to accept the column name which will be searched in the Where method, something like:

```
        public IQueryable<TEntity> GetEntities(string val)
        {
            TEntity entity = _DbContext.Set<TEntity>()
                 .Where(e => e.Col1.Contains(val));
            return entities;
        }
```

to be changed to

```
        public IQueryable<TEntity> GetEntities(string val, string colName)
        {
            TEntity entity = _DbContext.Set<TEntity>()
                 .WhereContains(val, colName);
            return entities;
        }
```

colName is the name of a string column.

I looked at https://blog.jeremylikness.com/blog/dynamically-build-linq-expressions/ but could not modify the example there for my needs.  The answer should be in the form of

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> WhereContains<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query, string value, string colName)
                    where TEntity : class
{
...
...
}
```

But I cant make it work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found a good [reference](http:////https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries) and was able to modify it:

```
public static IQueryable<T> TextFilter<T>(IQueryable<T> source, string[] colNames, string[] terms)
{
    if (colNames.Length == 0) return source;

    // T is a compile-time placeholder for the element type of the query.
    Type elementType = typeof(T);

    // Get all the properties on this specific type for colNames.
    List<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>();
    for (int i = 0; i < colNames.Length; i++)
    {
        PropertyInfo prop = elementType.GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string) && x.Name.ToLower() == colNames[i].ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
        if (prop == null) { return source; }
        props.Add(prop);
    }

    // Get the right overload of String.Contains.  Can be replaced e.g. with "Contains"
    MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) })!;

    // Create a parameter for the expression tree:
    // the 'x' in 'x => x.PropertyName.Contains("term")'
    // The type of this parameter is the query's element type
    ParameterExpression prm = Expression.Parameter(elementType);

    // Map each property to an expression tree node
    List<Expression> expressions = new List<Expression>();
    for (int i = 0; i < colNames.Length; i++)
    {
        expressions.Add(
            Expression.Call(
                Expression.Property(
                    prm,
                    props.ElementAt(i)
                ),
                containsMethod,
                Expression.Constant(terms[i])
            )
        );
    }

    // Combine all the resultant expression nodes using ||
    Expression body = expressions
        .Aggregate(
            (prev, current) => Expression.And(prev, current)
        );

    // Wrap the expression body in a compile-time-typed lambda expression
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, prm);

    // Because the lambda is compile-time-typed (albeit with a generic parameter), we can use it with the Where method
    return source.Where(lambda);
}
```

I was not able to make this work as an extension, so calling it is done with:

```
var qry= QueryableExtensions.TextFilter(_crudApiDbContext.Set<TEntity>()
    .Where(entity => entity.someColumn==someValue),
    filters.Keys.ToArray(), filters.Values.ToArray());
List<TEntity> entities = await qry
            .Skip(pageSize * (page - 1)).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
```